# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve the user name and a birthday from Facebook Graph API but I get `resultcode` as null in `onActivityResult`

My code

```
StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // make request to the /me API
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        gu=user;
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
};

Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this);
request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList( "basic_info","user_birthday"));
request.setCallback(mCallback );
// get active session
Session mFacebookSession = Session.getActiveSession();

if (mFacebookSession == null || mFacebookSession.isClosed()) {
    mFacebookSession = new Session(MainActivity.this);
}
mFacebookSession.openForRead(request);
```

}

And the onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String fullName = "";

    try { 
        fullName = gu.getName(); 
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    String birthdate = "";
    if (gu.getBirthday() != null && !gu.getBirthday().isEmpty()) {
        try { 
            String[] bdate=gu.getBirthday().split("/");
            lable.setText(gu.getBirthday());
            Month=Integer.parseInt(bdate[0]);
            Day=Integer.parseInt(bdate[1]);
            Year=Integer.parseInt(bdate[2]);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    name.setText(fullName);

    String Name=name.getText().toString();
    try {
        URL=URL+Day+"&month="+Month+"&year="+Year+"&name="+URLEncoder.encode(Name, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loader l=new loader(MainActivity.this);
    l.execute(URL);
}
```

The logcat

```
09-15 13:14:22.501: W/dalvikvm(1936): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c19648)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.abjadhawaz.lifepast/info.lifepast.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at info.lifepast.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:336)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
09-15 13:14:22.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):     ... 11 more
09-15 13:14:24.333: I/Process(1936): Sending signal. PID: 1936 SIG: 9
```

I got `NullPointerException` on this line

```
 Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

EDIT: I've updated my code I just get the graph user in the oncomplete method

Comment: post full logcat here

Comment: Hey @Tony, what is Session? Is it initialised? Also, make sure getActiveSession() doesn't return null...

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all of setText methods to onActivityResult method.

```
name.setText(fullName);  
lable.setText(user.getBirthday());
```

Then try again.

Comment: i updated my code according to ur answer but same error